# Cannot connect to Oracle Database with TNS

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, biztalk

I have the user name, password, the name of server and name of the database the database and the TNS connection string with the Server name = ABCDE

```
ABC =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 11.11.111.11)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 11.11.111.12)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABC)
)
)
```

In the URI properties of the comsumer apadper service I am giving the DataSourceName as the servername and the Service Name as  given in the TNS connection string ABC. It is not getting connected

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: what did you try so far? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG016

Comment: I am trying to connect to the orcale server by using SQL Developer. I added the connection string in to the tnsnamse.ora but Still getting the same eror

Comment: My suggestion is to follow the steps in section "Example of Troubleshooting a TNS-12154 Error" of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG397 to pinpoint the problem, once trivial causes like typos have been ruled out.